# BASH: Separate a line into words using tr

Tags: bash, tr

Part of my Bash assignment includes reading a text file, then separating each line into words and using them.

The words are separated by `|`, lines are separated by `\n`. We were told to use the `tr` command, but I couldn't find an elegant solution.

An example:

```
Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill
```

should give:

```
Hello
My
Name
Is
Bill
```

One word per iteration.

Comment: So what solution did you find, even if it’s not an elegant one?

Answer (score 4):

You only need one invocation of `tr` to do the job:

```
$ echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n'
Hello
My
Name
Is
Bill
$
```

The `-c` option is for 'the complement' of the characters in the first pattern; the `-s` option 'squeezes' out duplicate replacement characters.  So, anything that's not alphabetic is converted to a newline, but consecutive newlines are squeezed to a single newline.

Clearly, if you need to keep 'Everyone else | can | call | me | Fred' with the two words in the first line of output, then you have to work considerably harder:

```
$ echo "Everyone else | can | call | me | Fred" |
> tr '|' '\n' |
> sed 's/  *$//;s/^  *//'
Everyone else
can
call
me
Fred
$
```

The `sed` script here removes leading and trailing blanks, leaving intermediate blanks unchanged.  You can replace multiple blanks with a single blank if you need to, and so on and so forth.  You can't use `tr` to conditionally replace a given character (to change some blanks and leave others alone, for example).

Comment: This one looks pretty elegant this far, got some other issues meanwhile with another script, will try to solve it when i wake up!

Just another add-on,
If I need to save each of the words, what would be the best way ?

edit ->
Sorry for my ignorance :) just finished a c++ project and got an assignment on BASH even that we never studied it =] engineering school sucks :D

Comment: In which language?   `bash` -- use an array: `words=( $(echo "$phrase" | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n') )`.  (See `bash` manual on [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays), but also [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

Comment: This implementation will hold each of the words in the words array right?
words[0] = Hello , words[1] = My .... etc.. 
Shouldnt it be in a kind of loop ?
I will read the manuals.

Comment: The use of `[:alpha:]` character class with `tr` was something I had not seen before. I found [this manpage that shows all the character classes.](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using tr:

```
echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | tr -s '\| ' '\n'
```

OR if you decide to give awk a chance:

```
echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | awk -F '\|' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      sub(/ /, "", $i); print $i}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I must do it with tr :\ Thats the assignment request

Answer (score 1):

some other options:

**awk:**

```
awk -F'\\| '  -v OFS="\n" '$1=$1'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" |awk -F'\\| '  -v OFS="\n" '$1=$1'                                                                                              
Hello 
My 
Name 
Is 
Bill
```

**grep**

```
grep -o '[^ |]*'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill"|grep -o '[^ |]*' 
Hello
My
Name
Is
Bill
```

**sed**

```
sed 's/ | /\n/g'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" |sed 's/ | /\n/g'  
Hello
My
Name
Is
Bil
```

Comment: Great collection, but the `grep -o '[^ |]*'` will break incorrectly the next string `echo "Hello | My | First Name | Is | Bill"` :)

Comment: @jm666 you are right, the grep in answer works only for OP's example. The text in your comment, would be solved by  grep with a look-around regex. e.g. `grep -Po '^|\| \K.*?(?= \||$)'`

Answer (score 1):

My favorite perl :)

```
echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | perl -pe 's/\s*\|\s*/\n/g'
```

will remove the excessive spaces too, so

```
echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | perl -pe 's/\s*\|\s*/\n/g' | cat -vet
```

will print

```
Hello$
My$
Name$
Is$
Bill$
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it, converts '|' to newline, remove leading/trailing space:

```
echo "Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill" | tr '|' '\n' | tr -d [:blank:]
```

Comment: try with the `echo "Hello | My | First Name | Is | Bill"`

Comment: well that would not work :) I'm just providing a way to go from the OP's input to their output using only tr, which seems to be what they asked

Answer (score 0):

File temp: Hello | My | Name | Is | Bill

```
$ cat temp | tr '|' '\n' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Hello 
My 
Name 
Is 
Bill
$
```

The sed part gets rid of leading spaces (because there is a space between the '|' and the word.  This will also work for "Hello everyone | My | Name | Is | Bill":

```
$ cat temp | tr '|' '\n' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Hello everyone 
My 
Name 
Is 
Bill
$
```